# How to update an ExponentialSmoothing model on new data without refitting

Tags: python, statsmodels, exponential-smoothing

I'm trying to find the correct way to update an already fitted ExponentialSmoothing model on new data. My guess was like this:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

# some simple data (from statsmodels exponential smoothing example)
data = [41.7275,  24.0418,  32.3281,  37.3287,  46.2132,  29.3463, 36.4829,  42.9777,  48.9015,
        31.1802,  37.7179,  40.4202, 51.2069,  31.8872,  40.9783,  43.7725]

model = {'trend': 'add', 'seasonal_periods':4, 'seasonal':'add'}
m = ExponentialSmoothing(data[:15],**model).fit()
m_updated = ExponentialSmoothing(data[:16], **model).fit(**fitted_params)
```

Here comes the problem: fitted_params contains two unexpected keys: `initial_season` and `lamda`. When I delete these from the parameters dictionary the code works, but it seems that the season is recomputed every time. Another proof of this is that if I choose a model without seasonality, e.g. `model = {'trend': 'add'}`, after removing again `initial_season` and `lamda` the last line of the snippet above raises a `EstimationWarning: Model has no free parameters to estimate`.

So it seems that in this way I can update an ExponentialSmoothing model without seasonality, but I cannot do the same if the model is seasonal. Is this a bug, a feature not already implemented or the desired behaviour? Is there another way to do it for seasonal models (maybe using the HoltWintersResults class)?

Comment: I think that this thread is relevant: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6183

Comment: Adding two more links:
- this one shows how to deal with updates for state space models
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_news.html

- this one has the exponential smoothing model implementation that's capable of updating
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two implementations of the exponential smoothing model in the statsmodels library:

```
statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing
statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing), the former implementation, while having some limitations, allows for updates.

Here's how an update could be performed (based on [this documentation page](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_news.html)):

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing import ExponentialSmoothing

# some simple data (from statsmodels exponential smoothing example)
data = [41.7275,  24.0418,  32.3281,  37.3287,  46.2132,  29.3463, 36.4829,  42.9777,  48.9015,
        31.1802,  37.7179,  40.4202, 51.2069,  31.8872,  40.9783,  43.7725]
# slightly changed notation
model = {'trend': True, 'seasonal':4}
m = ExponentialSmoothing(data[:15],**model).fit()

m_updated = m.append(data[15:])

# this shows the effect of the update
m.news(m_updated,start=15,periods=4).summary()
```

If you investigate the parameters of both models, you'll notice that they are the same.

**Second approach**

In Feb 2022 the implementation of exponential smoothing model based on state space models has a bug:

> RuntimeWarning: ExponentialSmoothing should not be used with seasonal terms. It has a serious bug that has not been fixed. Instead use ETSModel.

After some digging I found out how one would update the model using the other implementation. From here on HW stands for the 'regular' Holt Winters implementation, HW_SS stands for the implementation based on state space models.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing import ExponentialSmoothing as HW_SS

# some simple data (from statsmodels exponential smoothing example)
data = [41.7275,  24.0418,  32.3281,  37.3287,  46.2132,  29.3463, 36.4829,  42.9777,  48.9015,
        31.1802,  37.7179,  40.4202, 51.2069,  31.8872,  40.9783,  43.7725]
# slightly changed notation
model = {'trend': True, 'seasonal':4}
m_ss = HW_SS(data[:15],**model).fit()
m_ss_forecast = m_ss.get_forecast(steps=5).summary_frame(alpha=0.10)['mean']
m_ss_updated = m_ss.append(data[15:])
m_ss_updated_forecast = m_ss_updated.get_forecast(steps=4).summary_frame(alpha=0.10)['mean']

from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing as HW
model = {'trend': 'add', 'seasonal_periods':4, 'seasonal':'add'}
m = HW(data[:15],**model).fit()
params_initial = {key:value for key, value in m.params.items() if 'initial' in key and 'season' not in key}
params_smoothing = {key:value for key, value in m.params.items() if 'smoothing' in key}

m_forecast = m.forecast(steps = 5)
m_updated = HoltWinters(data,
                        **model,
                        initialization_method='known',
                        **params_initial,
                        initial_seasonal=m.params['initial_seasons'])\
.fit(**params_smoothing,optimized=False)
m_updated_forecast = m_updated.forecast(steps = 4)
```

Note that `m_updated.params` and `m.params` are the same.

Here's a plot of all possible forecasts.

```
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(range(15,20),m_forecast, label = 'HW')
plt.plot(range(16,20),m_updated_forecast, label = 'HW updated')
plt.plot(range(15,20),m_ss_forecast, label = 'HW_SS')
plt.plot(range(16,20),m_ss_updated_forecast, label = 'HW_SS updated')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this feature wasn't implemented at the time I asked the question. Anyway, I'm glad this is now possible and thanks for pointing it out!